# Mysql Match and count in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an trouble with count product with some conditions on the same table..

Table structure:

```
INSERT INTO `filter` (`filter_seq_id`, `group_id`, `product_seq_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 10),
(2, 1, 11),
(3, 1, 12),
(4, 1, 13),
(5, 2, 14),
(6, 2, 15),
(7, 2, 16),
(8, 2, 17),
(9, 3, 18),
(10, 3, 19),
(11, 3, 20),
(12, 3, 21),
(13, 4, 20),
(14, 4, 11),
(15, 4, 27),
(16, 4, 29),
(17, 5, 11),
(18, 5, 20),
(19, 5, 27),
(20, 5, 13);
```

Here i want count distinct product_seq_id for the group_id (1,2,3) only if product_seq_id also exits in both (4,5) group id..

for example:

- group_id -> 1 found product_seq_id 11 in 4,5 so distinct count is 1
- group_id -> 2 found nothing
- group_id -> 3 found product_seq_id 20 in 4,5 so distinct count is 1

i have tried below query its not returning has i expect
its counting if product_seq_id exists in any one of (4,5)

And i want to count only if product_seq_id exits on both "4" and "5" group_id

```
SELECT 
    `f`.`group_id`, count(distinct f.product_seq_id) as count
FROM
    filter f
        JOIN
    filter ff ON `ff`.`product_seq_id` = `f`.`product_seq_id`
        AND `f`.`group_id` IN (1,2,3)
        AND `ff`.`group_id` IN (4,5)
GROUP BY `f`.`group_id`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/996c1/1

Comment: Does the result need to say that in group 2 the count is 0? or are just 2 rows (with group 1 and group 3) fine enough?

Comment: @Mojooo just 1 and 3 is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

`select f123.GROUP_ID, count(f123.PRODUCT_SEQ_ID) 
from (select product_seq_id from filter where group_id=4) f4 
inner join (select product_seq_id from filter where group_id=5) f5 
on f4.product_seq_id = f5.product_seq_id 
inner join (select group_id, product_seq_id from filter where group_id<4) f123 
on f123.product_seq_id = f5.product_seq_id
group by GROUP_ID order by GROUP_ID`

The first two subselects selects all of the product_seq_id which are in filter in the group 4 or 5. Those 2 list are joined together only if both contain the same product_seq_id.
The Result of this is all the product_seq_id which are both in group 4 and group 5 (in this example 11 and 20)

Next this result is joined with the last subselect, which selects all group_id and product_seq_id in the groups 1 to 3. They are only joined if they contain any product_seq_id, which is in the previous result of the other join (so if they contain the product_seq_id 11 or 20). The Result of this looks like this:

`Group_ID, Product_Seq_ID
        1              11
        3              20`

This result is then grouped by the Group_ID and the amount of product_seq_id in each group is counted

EDIT: Added Explanation

Comment: can you explain ? i confused :(

Comment: @Raj I edited my post. I hope you can understand it now better